# Unity -- Problem with saving List with BinaryFormatter

Tags: unity-game-engine, binary

I have made a Game and want to save my Inventory which is a List of Skins (class I created) with the BinaryFormatter. But now I get always an Error if I want to Save or Load this List as you can see below.

[image: Error I get after Save or Load]

Here is the "Skins" Class I made

[image: Skins Class]

The picture below shows the Script where my Inventorylist is in which I want to save.

[image]

And thats the Script I use to save and load my List

[image]

Does anyone know what Im doing wrong?
Would appreciate every help!

Comment: Please add the error message and all relevant code as **text** not as images! You can use the `{ }` button to format it than.

Comment: [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/serializing-sprites.278563/) is at least a workaround where someone used the path to file for serialization as string. Never tried [this one](https://forum.unity.com/threads/released-runtime-serialization-for-unity-extremely-easy-solution-to-save-your-gameplay-data.325812/) but maybe it works for you